# While tapping spacebar keyboard behaves strange - Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, keyboard-events

For one of our supporting project, there is a keyboard issue as shown in the image while tapping space bar keyboard freezing [image: image here] and it occurs only for this app (i.e. it is not related to the phone OS). This app is developed in Objective C and we haven't used any third party library for keyboard related things. Tried `shouldChangeTextInRange` delegate method and we are not getting any space character while happening this issue. Overall keyboard behaves little strange. Requesting your valuable support. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is related to a third party library using. Working fine when removed that library. Not sure about the root cause on the issue.